# Can access response inside ng-click with ui route

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angularjs-routing, angularjs-ng-click

I have a problem. Im confused because value from ng-model and ng-click can used inside templateUrl ui router. So, I have a template , example : thread.html. There are ng-click inside thread.html. So like this

Thread.html -> button ng-click (go to answer.html)

Btw i put component answer in thread-controller. Am I wrong ?

So, I think the problem is ui router. I didn't get data and can showing in answer's table. How can i fix my problem ? Please give me solution. Thanks

**Configuration UI route**

```
app.config(function($stateProvider) {

    var home = {
      name: 'home',
      url: '/home',
      controller: 'admin-rv-controller',
      templateUrl: 'templates/home.html'
    };

    var thread = {
        name: 'thread',
        url: '/thread',
        controller: 'thread-controller',
        templateUrl: 'templates/table-thread.html'
    };

    var answer = {
        name: 'answer',
        url: '/answer',
        controller: 'thread-controller',
        templateUrl: 'templates/table-answer.html'
    };

    var tag = {
        name: 'tag',
        url: '/tag',
        controller: 'tag-controller',
        templateUrl: 'templates/table-tag.html'
    };

    var trending_tag = {
        name: 'trending-tag',
        url: '/trending-tag',
        controller: 'trending-tag-controller',
        templateUrl: 'templates/table-trending-tag.html'
    };

    var form_trending_tag = {
        name: 'form-trending-tag',
        parent: 'trending-tag',
        url: '/form-trending-tag',
        controller: 'trending-tag-controller',
        templateUrl: 'templates/form-trending-tag.html'
    };

    var category = {
        name: 'category',
        url: '/category',
        controller: 'category-controller',
        templateUrl: 'templates/table-category.html'
    };

    var user = {
        name: 'user',
        url: '/user',
        controller: 'user-controller',
        templateUrl: 'templates/table-user.html'
    };

    $stateProvider.state(home);
    $stateProvider.state(thread);
    $stateProvider.state(answer);
    $stateProvider.state(tag);
    $stateProvider.state(trending_tag);
    $stateProvider.state(category);
    $stateProvider.state(user);
    $stateProvider.state(form_trending_tag);
});
```

**Thread.html**

```
<tbody ng-repeat="data in result">
     <tr>
        <td>
            {{ startnumber + $index + 1 }}
        </td>
        <td>
            {{ data.item._id }}
        </td>
        <td>
            {{ data.item.title }}
        </td>
        <td>
            {{ data.item.category.label }}
        </td>
        <td>
            {{ data.item.user.name }}
        </td>
        <td width="30%">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="ListAnswer(data.item)"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i> View Answer</button>                
            <button class="btn btn-success" ng-click="FiturThread(data, data.item)"><i class="fa fa-toggle-on"></i> {{ data.btn_label }}</button>
         </td>
  </tr>
```

**Thread Controller**

```
//list answer
    $scope.ListAnswer = function(data) {

        var url = "http://192.168.0.253:81/agnes/ruang-vemale/api/v1/answer/listAnswerThread/3c8dd5e26e7e653c9823728f90fcbadf39c2651e/";
        var parsing_id = JSON.stringify(data._id);
        var page = 0;
        var a = angular.fromJson({"data" : "{\"username\": \"newshubid\",\"data\":{\"threadId\": "+ parsing_id +",\"page\":"+ page +",\"length\":10,\"orderby\":{\"field\":\"updated_at\",\"type\":\"DESC\"}}}"});

        var param = $.param(a);

        HttpService("POST", url, param, function(response){

            $scope.parsing = angular.fromJson(response.message.data);

            $scope.result = {};

            angular.forEach($scope.parsing, function(item){
                console.log(item.answer);
                //$scope.result[item.answer._id] =  item.answer;

                $scope.result[item.answer._id] =  {
                                            item_ans : item.answer,
                                            btn_label : item.active === 0 ? "Off" : "On"
                                        };
                $state.go('answer');
            });
        });
};
```

**Result From Answer**

```
_id: "58a1230ca6551f73694c6761"
accepted:0
active:1
answer:"balas 1.5"
created_at: "2017-02-13 10:07:56"
down_vote: 0
level: 5
marker :"y0gnfqwl"
parent_id: "58a122f3a6551f208a2fd8b1"
priority: 0
revision: 0
thread_id: "589c0484a6551f948e1d6914"
up_vote: 0
updated_at: "2017-02-13 10:07:56"
user_id:"58942d43a6551fd7123bdcb1"
```

Comment: could you put a working plunkr of the code. and is console.log(item.answer) printing?

Comment: Try putting the ng-repeat on the tr, not the tbody

Comment: @user93 I edited my code